# Executing Python3 function via cmd line via argparse in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, module

Question: How do I use the argparse package to run my Python3 module from command line in Windows? Background and code examples follow.

I am trying to write a function that can be run from Windows command line. Currently, I am developing in Python 3 on Windows 7, using the Spyder IDE. I do not have access to modify any Windows enviornment vars. Additionally, my function will use keyword arguments, all set to a default value if not supplied-- I would like the user to be able to call the function using either ordered arguments (i.e. without writing the keywords in the function call) OR by using unordered arguments (i.e. by writing the keywords in the function call, e.g. `do_that_thing(bar='hello', foo='goodbye')`, see example below).

I place the command line inputs in the Spyder run settings dialogue box under Command Line Options: `'hello' 'goodbye'`. The error message i recieve in the Spyder console is: `can't open file`

I have made a sincere effort to consult the documentation for argparse and other questions on this site and others. Could you verify at least that I am using argparse correctly with regards to my previous description?  I'm thinking that my issue is that I can't modify the system path. Although I thought Spyder would allow me to run this within some sort of shell so that modifying system variables is not needed.  Thanks!

```
import argparse

def do_that_thing(foo=None, bar=None, cat=None):

    if foo is not None:
        print(foo)
    if bar is not None:
        print(bar)
    if cat is not None:
        print(cat)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Extract user inputs
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Add arguments
    parser.add_argument('foo', help='This is foo!', nargs='?', default=None)
    parser.add_argument('bar', help='This is bar!', nargs='?', default=None)
    parser.add_argument('cat', help='The superior species!', nargs='?', default=None)

    # Get args
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Call function
    do_that_thing(args.foo, args.bar, args.cat)
```

Comment: Hrm... don't see why this warrented a down vote. Was it because of my formatting issue?

Comment: One possibility is that it''s unclear what you're asking.  "figure this out": figure *what* out?  "Alas, it is still not working for me."  In what way?  Does it give you an error message?  Is there an input it misbehaves for?  If so, what is it?  "I can't get it to work correctly": by this point it's just getting silly. :-)

Comment: @DSM I have made edits per your suggestion so as to be more specific and less 'silly'. Better?

Comment: tried with your command line args `'hello' 'goodbye'`: spyder does not treat the quotes gracefully (works perfectly with quotes on the command line). try just `hello goodbye` as arguments in spyder.